# Ruby Array Maniplulation - Scanning and Counting

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm trying to read though each string in the array and count the number of times the letters occurs in each position (ie 1 , 2, 3, 4). How am I not using the multidimensional array and += operator correctly?

```
def scan_str(arr)
   position = [[]]
   x = 0
   arr.select do |word|
   word.length.times do |i|
        if word.index('G') == x
            position[x+1,0] += 1 
            x += 1
        elsif word.index('A') == x
            position[x+1,1] += 1
            x += 1
        elsif word.index('T') == x
            position[x+1,2] += 1
            x += 1
        elsif word.index('C') == x
            position[x+1,3] += 1
            x += 1
        else
            x += 1
        end
    end
end

p position


end

input = ["CTAGATA","CCCGAT","AAATT","TTCAAATGA"]
scan_str(input)
```

Thanks this is helpful. But now how do I manipulate the array without the error message "`[]': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)"... There must be something I'm not getting about the index or position [][] syntax.

```
def scan_str(arr)
   position = [[]]
   z=arr.count
   x = 0
   arr.select do |word|
        if word.index('G') == x
            position[y][0] += (countG =+ 1)/z
            x += 1
            y += 1
        elsif word.index('A') == x
            position[y][1] += (countA =+ 1)/z
            x += 1
            y += 1
        elsif word.index('T') == x
            position[y][2] += (countT =+ 1)/z
            x += 1
            y += 1
        elsif word.index('C') == x
            position[y][3] += (countC =+ 1)/z
            x += 1
            y += 1
        else
            x += 1
            y += 1
        end
    end

p position


end

input = ["CTAGATA","CCCGAT","AAATT","TTCAAATGA"]
scan_str(input)
```

Comment: can u use hash instead?

Comment: can you post your desired output?

Comment: The syntax `position[x+1,0]` does not reference into the array of arrays as you might think. You don't have a "multi-dimensional array" in your question, you have an `Array` where the first element happens to be an `Array`

Comment: In ruby `position[1,3]` doesn't mean `position[1][3]`.

Comment: Desired output would be  { 
 1 :  {“C” : 50%, “A” : 25%, “T” : 25%, "G" : 0%
}

 2 :  {"C" : 25%, “A” : 25%, “T” : 50%, “G” : 0%
}
etc.....
.....

Comment: You should edit the question to include the desired output, rather than putting it in a comment.  I suggest you do that to head off any additional downvotes, or to have your question put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

AS they almost answered it in comments:

`position[1,3]` is 3 elements from 2nd position, counting from 0.
Correct syntax is: `position[1][3]`.

ps. Example:

```
arr=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] 
arr[1][2]
# 6 # 3rd element from 2nd array, counting from 0!
```

Answer (score 0):

As the problem with your code has been explained, I would like to suggest a more "Ruby-like" approach:

```
TEST = ['G', 'A', 'T', 'C']

def scan_str(arr)
  TEST.each_with_object({}) {|c,h| h[c] = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|line, hh| \
    line.chars.each_with_index {|s,i| hh[i] += 1 if s==c}}}
end

arr = ["CTAGATA","CCCGAT","AAATT","TTCAAATGA"]
scan_str(arr)
  # => {"G"=>{3=>2, 7=>1}, \
  # =>  "A"=>{2=>2, 4=>3, 6=>1, 0=>1, 1=>1, 3=>1, 5=>1, 8=>1}, \ 
  # =>  "T"=>{1=>2, 5=>2, 3=>1, 4=>1, 0=>1, 6=>1}, \
  # =>  "C"=>{0=>2, 1=>1, 2=>2}}
```

A few points:

- It is probably most convenient to put the results in a hash.  Here I have `scan_str` returning a hash whose keys are the elements of `TEST`.  The value of each key is itself a hash, with each key being a line offset position and the associated value being the number of times the letter given by the outer key is located at that position.
- I first iterate over the elements of TEST using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with the default object being an empty hash `{}`.  Inside the block the hash is referenced by `h`.  The alternative would be to define an empty has (`h = {}`) in the line above and then use `TEST.each {|c|...` instead.  Had I done that it would have also been necessary to add the line `h` at the end of the method, so that the hash would be returned.
- For each element `c` of `TEST`, I iterate over the lines of the array, again using `each_with_object`.  This time, however, the default value of the object is `Hash.new(0)` which creates a hash with default values of zero.  By doing that, when `hh[i] += 1` is executed in the inner loop, we don't have to check if `hh` has a key `i`; if it does not, Ruby first executes `hh[i] = 0` (zero being the default value), then `hh[i] += 1 => 1`.
- For each line, `line.chars` converts the line to an array of characters. I then iterate with [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).  Inside the block, the character (string of length one) and line offset are referenced by `s` and `i` respectively.

There are a couple of ways to obtain the result you want.  The first, and probably easiest, would be just to change the code I've already offered.  I'll do that later today.
The second is to use the code above as a "helper method".

**Use helper" method**

To use the code we already have, rename the `scan_str` method above to `scan_str_helper` and add this:

```
def scan_str(arr)
  h = scan_str_helper(arr)
  posh = Hash[h.values.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq.map {|e| \
    [e,Hash[TEST.zip([0]*TEST.size)]]}]
  h.each {|k,v| v.each {|kk,vv| posh[kk][k] += vv}}
  posh.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v),hp| tot = 1.0 * v.values.reduce(&:+); \
    hp[k] = Hash[v.keys.zip(v.values.map {|e| e/tot})]}
end

scan_str(arr)
  # {3=>{"G"=>0.5, "A"=>0.25, "T"=>0.25, "C"=>0.0}, 7=>{"G"=>1.0, "A"=>0.0, "T"=>0.0, "C"=>0.0},
  #  2=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>0.5, "T"=>0.0, "C"=>0.5},   4=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>0.75, "T"=>0.25, "C"=>0.0},
  #  6=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>0.5, "T"=>0.5, "C"=>0.0},   0=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>0.25, "T"=>0.25, "C"=>0.5},
  #  1=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>0.25, "T"=>0.5, "C"=>0.25},
  #  5=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>0.3333333333333333, "T"=>0.6666666666666666, "C"=>0.0},
  #  8=>{"G"=>0.0, "A"=>1.0, "T"=>0.0, "C"=>0.0}}
```

A few more notes:

- `h.values.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq` => [3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 5, 8]` merely constructs an array of the position offsets that contain one or more TEST elements.
- `h.keys.zip([0]*TEST.size) => h.keys.zip([0, 0, 0, 0]) => Hash[["G",0], ["A",0], ["T",0], ["C",0]]] => {"G"=>0, "A"=>0, "T"=>0, "C"=>0}`, so for `e` = 3 (say), `Hash[3, {"G"=>0, "A"=>0, "T"=>0, "C"=>0}] => {3=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>0, "T"=>0, "C"=>0}}`.
- Instead of `h.keys.zip([0]*TEST.size)`, you may be tempted to write `a = [0]*TEST.size; TEST.zip(a)`.  That doesn't work.  I'll leave it to you to figure out why.
- `h.each {|k,v| v.each {|kk,vv| posh[kk][k] += vv}}` fills the hash `posh =>
  # {3=>{"G"=>2, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>0}, 7=>{"G"=>1, "A"=>0, "T"=>0, "C"=>0},
  #  2=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>2, "T"=>0, "C"=>2}, 4=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>3, "T"=>1, "C"=>0},
  #  6=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>0}, 0=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>2},
  #  1=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>2, "C"=>1}, 5=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>2, "C"=>0},
  #  8=>{"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>0, "C"=>0}}`.
- The last line merely converts the numbers of occurrences to fractions. For example, `3=>{"G"=>2, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>0}` is converted to `3=>{"G"=>0.5, "A"=>0.25, "T"=>0.25, "C"=>0.0}`

**Modification of Initial Code**

```
  def scan_str(arr)
    a = Array.new(arr.map(&:size).max).map {|e| \
          Hash[TEST.zip(Array.new(TEST.size,0))]}
    arr.each {|s| s.chars.each_with_index {|c,i| TEST.each \
      {|ss| a[i][ss] += 1 if c == ss}}}
    Hash[a.map.with_index {|h,i| tot = 1.0 * h.values.reduce(&:+); tot > 0.0 ? \
      [i, Hash[h.keys.zip(h.values.map {|e| e/tot})]] : nil}.compact]
  end
```

- The first statement creates an array `a`, the ith element corresponding to character offset i in each line.  The value of the ith element is the hash referred to in the next note, with all values equal to zero.
- The second statement fills the array `a`:
  `# => [{"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>2}, {"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>2, "C"=>1},
   # =>  {"G"=>0, "A"=>2, "T"=>0, "C"=>2}, {"G"=>2, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>0},
   # =>  {"G"=>0, "A"=>3, "T"=>1, "C"=>0}, {"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>2, "C"=>0},
   # =>  {"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>1, "C"=>0}, {"G"=>1, "A"=>0, "T"=>0, "C"=>0},
   # =>  {"G"=>0, "A"=>1, "T"=>0, "C"=>0}]`.
- The last statement converts each element of `a` to a hash if the sum of the values is positive; else to `nil`.  `compact` removes all elements that are `nil`. Putting `Hash[` and the beginning and `]` at the end converts the array to a hash, which is returned by `scan_str`.
- Note this approach gives the same result as the method that the used the "helper" method, though the order of the elements of the hash is different.

Comment: Thanks this is definitely getting there - however desired output would be "Position 1 - {"C" : 50%, "A" : 25%, "T" : 25%, "G" : 0% }                   Position 2 - {"C" : 25%, "A" : 25%, "T" : 50%, "G" : 0% }" etc etc

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your methods, but would be curious how you swap from letter counts to character position counts while still using the hash. I think I'm missing how this is possible since a new case of key/value instances must be created for each character position.

Comment: I get a "(eval):43: undefined method `with_index' for #<Array:0x13d738> (NoMethodError)
 from (eval):49" when I try to compile 'Modification of Initial Code' code.

Comment: The 'Modification of Initial Code` works for me (Ruby 2.0).  Did you remember to include `TEST = ['G', 'A', 'T', 'C']` before the method definition and `arr = ["CTAGATA", "CCCGAT", "AAATT", "TTCAAATGA"]` and `scan_str(arr)` after?  I didn't repeat that part of the code but it's of course needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is no very beautiful and should probably be split into a few functions:

```
a = ["CTAGATA","CCCGAT","AAATT","TTCAAATGA"]

p Hash[
 a.map{|sub| sub.chars.with_index(1).to_a}
  .flatten(1).group_by(&:last)
  .map{|pos, values| 
    [pos, Hash[values.group_by{|char,|char}.map{|char,s|[char, s.size.to_f/values.length]}]]
  }
] #=> {1=>{"C"=>0.5, "A"=>0.25, "T"=>0.25}, 2=>{"T"=>0.5, "C"=>0.25, "A"=>0.25}, 3=>
```